# Issue updating multiple contributions

Tags: civicontribute, profile, dates

The date field seems to break when trying to update multiple contribution dates.
Drupal 7, Civi 5.10.4 and 5.11, Shoreditch enabled or disabled.  Also happens to break the Menu, KAM, Shoreditch, or Classic.

I was not able to replicate on the demo - and there are other contributions I am able to bulk update without issue - any ideas as to why this would happen?

UPDATE: The issue seems to be tied to one contribution - I was able to update all the other contributions, once I skipped that single one.  Nothing in that contribution seems to indicate an issue - will investigate further.

[image]